# A Soldier With an Asymmetrical Shoulder: Which Weapons Would He Use?

Tags: weapons, history

Let us assume that we are reading a historical fantasy about a Chinese or Korean soldier set anywhen between the 11th and 15th centuries CE.  Not exciting, so here's the real standout--his right shoulder is a bit lower than his left, so the king's army would not apply him to undergo military training.  He does get some divine intervention, but since they only taught him and never physically altered him (unless "gods teaching a mortal martial arts" counts), that's not relevant to the question, mentioned only to reduce confusion.

So, using the setting described above, **which weapons would this soldier with the asymmetrical shoulder wield to compensate for that disability?**

Comment: Does he still have a full range of motion and strength with his arms?

Comment: @nick012000  I don't see why not, if that's possible.

Comment: How would he be disabled, if that's the case? He might just need some armor that's been custom-modified to fit him?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you don't consider "asymmetrical" as a hint of disability.  One shoulder is not in sync with the other.

Comment: What difficulties do you see this disability as causing them? Prejudice due to not meeting the cultural standards of aesthetics?

Comment: @nick012000  Could you reword that?  I have a hard time following what you're trying to say.

Comment: The definition of a "disability" is that it *disables*, and I'm not certain what difficulties that this disability would cause someone.

Comment: The dominant shoulder is normally a bit more developed and a bit higher than the other shoulder by default. So the question becomes how much asymetrical the shoulders are and how it changes his capabilities. He has to lose something or else there is no reason not to apply him in the army. You could give him something in return though. But that depends on how terribly asymetric this shoulder is. Why the asymetry is there is also important. A scoliosis (layman: spine tilt) or the shoulder joint grows lower on one end?

Comment: My hips are asymmetric – one turns out more – and the only disability therefrom is that I cannot ride a bicycle.

Answer (score 7):

"his right shoulder is a bit lower than his left"

I don't understand how this is a disability. Or at least a real problem.

Like if he can still use a shield he is fine.
Shield + weapon, mostly spear, is the dominant combo in history. 
He does not have to raise it above his head as well.
Just holding it out a bit in front and covering his body from the neck downward is fine.

If he can use bows he should still be fine.

He can even use a spear, or similar 2 handed weapon, with his taller upfront and shorter one back.

He can be a cavalry man riding with a spear/lance in his main arm while the other one uses the reins.

Honestly I don't understand how is it a big deal!

Comment: I don't understand how you don't consider asymmetrical shoulders a disability.

Comment: Maybe in some context it is. Sure.
But for a soldiers context it can barely be a problem.
It's more of an inconvenience. 
Especially he said "his right shoulder is a bit lower"
He is not missing it, it's not half length, it's not coming out of his belly. 
Its a bit lower. 
He can still do all what I said above without a problem.
I mean it's like saying can a one armed man be a waiter? 
Yes. It will take him more time to bring the food and drinks, but he will do it.

Comment: @JohnWDailey we don't understand why you do. Asymmetry isn't unusual. It's why they have to custom fit your glasses when you get your perception. The question is to vague. Does this asymmetry limit the range of motion? And armor would be impacted by this long before weapons. It's why we have tailors.